# Design implementation for Page objects in UI Automation

Tags: widget, ui-automation, pageobjects

I am struggling with this design of UI Automation over the past few weeks. What we have come up with for Widget-based UI Automation, using Page objects sounds like a very tedious idea that's going to get out of control and unmanageable very quickly.

I am asking this question here just in case, anybody might be able to throw some new ideas or ways of implementing this.

We are trying to automate, using page objects, Widget-based UI. Now, these widgets are supposed to be reusable. And they have got different layouts that might differ in the elements, their CSS, or so.

The problem is, the layouts for each widget, could be anywhere between 1-20 or so. Moreover, there are composite widgets, that are composed of some of the other widgets and have their own layouts as well. So all in all, the composite widgets, in addition with their own layouts, will also encompass the different layouts of its underlying widgets.

The kind of framework we have come up with, is creating interfaces and implementations for each of the different layouts of each widget (even though 90% of the layouts for one widget will almost always change in only CSS; the html remains the same. The CSS classes are hardcoded into the layout definitions. ). I am already overwhelmed by the amount of maintenance we are looking forward to.

Can anyone come up with a better solution? It will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the page object the emphasis is more about the services they provide (e.g. click on button, enter text in textfield, etc.). With that being said, will the locators be consistent that is for a widget, will it generally have the same buttons and input fields? From your info, it seems like those will change...But with so many different layouts and composite and usages for a widget, it might not be a good solution to go this route. As page objects go, you build what you need at a minimum, that is if you use buttons, input fields in the test, of course you have to have locators for them.